# How to expose a url with parameters in asp.net for developing two way sms system

Tags: c#, asp.net, infobip

I have to develop a two way sms system.I contacted Infobip for that.I have done with sending messages on short code using http api exposed by them.Now I want to receive messages send on reply by that number.

In the pdf send by Infobip they told be to expose a url so that they can push the received message in my system.

As an example, if you provide the following URL:
http://some.server.com/incoming_sms.php?who=%sender%&what=%text%&output=xml

How to expose such a url to others?

Answer (score 1):

Provide/expose in this sense have the same meaning. If you create a web server which listens for requests on some end-point, it means it's "exposed" (if it's publicly available, ofc.), and you can "provide" URL of that endpoint to anyone.

In your particular case, such URL would be used by Infobip to deliver you reports of received messages, and for that purpose, you should provide them that URL.

Anyway, if I didn't hit the spot, Infobip's support is great, you may contact them at support@infobip.com.